# Android Webview shouldoverrideurlloading only called when url redirected

Tags: android, webview, redirect

I have a WebView inside of an activity and it has a webviewclient with shouldoverrideurlloading.

When I load **https://mobile.twitter.com/**, shouldoverrideurlloading not called because it doesn't redirected,
but it works when load **http://mobile.twitter.com.** **(http protocol redirects to http)**

I have tested almost 20 urls, shouldoverrideurlloading called only when url redirected.

Is there any conditions or settings required to use shouldoverrideurlloading in any cases? (Except POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `loadUrl` on WebView, it won't call `shouldoverrideurlloading` because you don't need it, and you can decide if you want the `WebView` to load the URL, or you want to handle it on your own before passing to the `WebView`.
`shouldoverrideurlloading` will be called when the `WebView` changes it's URL not by your will, but for example when user clicks on the link in the `WebView`, or the redirect happens.